# How can data parameters be passed to a factory create( ) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, factory

I have this snippet:

```
// In __constructor arguments:
\Magento\Framework\FlagFactory $flagFactory
...
// This is not called in __constructor:
$flag = $this->flagFactory->create(['flag_code' => 'something']);
var_dump($flag->getFlagCode());
```

It displays null.
I var dumped into `Magento\Framework\Flag::_construct()` this `var_dump($this->getData('flag_code')); exit;` and still null.

Anyone has an ideea how to set a parameter in $data array of the create() function ?
I'm in developer mode.
The object manager factory would be `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic::create`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use code like

```
$this->flagFactory->create(['data' => ['flag_code' => 'something']]);
```